# Shadow doesnt show inside another div element

Tags: html, css

I have this html code

and now I want to put this html inside "SHOULD COME HERE" below

```
<div class="box-text">
<h3>Effect 2</h3>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.box-text {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;   
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 2
 * ===============================================*/
 .box-text:before, .box-text:after {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    -moz-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);  
    -ms-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);  
    -o-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);  
    -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg); 
    background: transparent;
    bottom: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    content: ' ';
    height: 10px;
    left: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);  
    width: 40%;
    z-index: -1;  
}

.box-text:after  {
 
    -moz-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);  
    -ms-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);  
    -o-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);   
    left: auto;  
    right: 12px;  
    transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);  
}
```

And if I want to do this, the shadow of the 1st code set disappears. I am new to html/css and it somehow doesn't make sense to me why the shadow would disappear and I would be happy for any tips. If not it's ok as well :) here is the code I want to put it inside:

```css
body {background:#ccc}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
  }
  
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}

.box-text {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;   
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 2
 * ===============================================*/
 .box-text:before, .box-text:after {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    -moz-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);  
    -ms-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);  
    -o-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);  
    -webkit-transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg); 
    background: transparent;
    bottom: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    content: ' ';
    height: 10px;
    left: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: skew(-5deg) rotate(-5deg);  
    width: 40%;
    z-index: -1;  
}

.box-text:after  {
 
    -moz-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);  
    -ms-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);  
    -o-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);   
    left: auto;  
    right: 12px;  
    transform: skew(5deg) rotate(5deg);  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>

        <!-- SHOULD COME HERE -->
        <div class="box-text">
          <h3>Effect 2</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what "the 1st code set" is but if you take out `z-index: -1;` you get two white eyebrows appearing.

Comment: Well.. my post used to make sense until someone edited my post.. It was my first time posting and now Im just even more confused, since I dont really need any eyebrows

Answer (score -1):

For those wondering, I had to delete the style attributes inside html:

```
style="background-color:#aaa;
```

Still dont get why.. but I'll update once I know